# LinkButton within UpdatePanel works fine until I try to use html markup as the text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, updatepanel, asplinkbutton

I have a composite control where I'm adding a `LinkButton` dynamically. This control is inside of an `UpdatePanel`.

If I set the text of the `LinkButton` to something simple, just text (i.e. click here to edit) then it does as intended and I'm able to asynchronously handle the request.

However, if I attempt to use any *html* markup at all (i.e. `<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>`) as the text, it still works but causes a full page refresh.

This is incredibly confusing and I simply don't understand why html markup is causing a post-back but text is not.

Example trimmed down:

```
Public Class LinkBase
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements INamingContainer

    Private ReadOnly _linkButton As LinkButton = New LinkButton()


    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        Controls.Clear()
        '_linkButton.Text = "Click here to edit" <-- works
        _linkButton.Text = "<span class='fa fa-edit'></span>" <-- causes refresh
        Controls.Add(_linkButton)

        MyBase.CreateChildControls()
    End Sub
```

End Class

**Update**

My custom control looks like this:

```
<custom:EditLink Text="Edit Me" />
```

Which renders as:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('shortened_ListView$l00','')">
    Edit Me
</a>
```

And if I use:

```
<custom:EditLink Text='<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>' />
```

It renders as:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('shortened_ListView$l00','')">
    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
</a>
```

This is as expected, as the `Text` property is the default inner property, so you can set it directly (i.e. Text) or use the inner content. Now the reason I'm setting it directly is because I technically have other child controls within my `<custom:EditLink>` that serve other purposes.

But again, when I use html it causes a page refresh. When I do not, such as "Edit Me" it uses the ajax method of update panel.

Comment: do you want this "<span class='fa fa-edit'></span>" as the text of your button? or do you want it to be rendered as an HTML dom element

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier Rendered, just like if you were to have something like `<a><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>`. And text as a property is the default inner property for the linkbutton control, but I have other nested properties (i.e. reason for composite control) that have other purposes. I'll update my question to show how it's rendered.